# Python3 Regex groupdict not working properly

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Using Python 3.4.3

I'm trying to do a regex to split CSS like identifiers. My pattern is:

`pattern = re.compile("(?P<tag>[^.#]+)?(#(?P<iḍ>[^.#]+))?(?P<classes>([.][^.#]+)+)?")`

My test string is `h2#label`. When I do the match, the groups I get are `('h2', '#label', 'label', None, None)` which is correct.

If I get the `groupdict` of the match I get `{'classes': None, 'iḍ': 'label', 'tag': 'h2'}` which also looks correct. However, when I try to retrieve the value of `id` I get a result as if it's not present.

Doing `"id" in match.groupdict()` yields `False` and doing "match.groupdict().get("id")`yields`None`.

Any idea what's wrong here and how to solve it?

Comment: See [tinycss: CSS parser for Python](https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @Wictor I know that parsing CSS is a solved problem. This was part of a larger thing that I was trying to do from scratch. I don't need this to work as I can think of workarounds, but it seems like incorrect behavior.

Comment: You used `?P<iḍ>`, not `?P<id>`, thus there is no Group `id`. So, everything works correctly, and you just made a typo.

Comment: Great. Thanks. That's what happens when you map > to a weird key and miss on typing. If you want, just post it as an answer and I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the typo: instead of `'iḍ'` type `'id'`.

```
pattern = re.compile("(?P<tag>[^.#]+)?(#(?P<id>[^.#]+))?(?P<classes>([.][^.#]+)+)?")
```